# R: data frame from permutations

Tags: r

Assume we have the following list:

```
L <- list(c(1, 1), c(2, 2), c(3, 3))
```

I'm looking for all possible unique rearrangement of `L` without replacement (i.e. permutations).

The result should be a data frame with `factorial(length(L))` number of rows and `length(L)*2` number of columns. In our example, `ncol = 3*2` and `nrow = 3!`:

```
allPossibleCombinations(L)

  1 2 3 4 5 6
1 1 1 2 2 3 3
2 1 1 3 3 2 2
3 2 2 1 1 3 3
4 2 2 3 3 1 1
5 3 3 1 1 2 2
6 3 3 2 2 1 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `permn` from `combinat`

```
library(combinat)
m1 <- t(sapply(permn(L), unlist))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.